# Конструкторы в Java

Tags: java, конструктор

Здравствуйте, скажите, пожалуйста, какя разница между конструкторами:

```
int age;
string name;
Man (int age, string name){
  age=age;
  name=name;
}

Man (int age, string name){
  this.age=age;
  this.name=name;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом вы не установите значение у полей класса. Это называется сокрытие переменных([Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)). [Хороший ответ о сокрытии на SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092165/1646082).

Comment: а, почему так будет?

Comment: @MuscledBoy это потому что происходит сокрытие переменных, я добавил описание в ответ что это такое.

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться